# How to make a code that detects repeating digits in a number python?

Tags: python, validation, input, digits

I want a simple code that can detect if number contains a repeated digit or not.
In python
without counter method.
For example,
if I enter 1234555
it sends a message that tells me invalid input

```
def isUnique(number):
    numberSet = set(list(number))
    if len(number) == len(numberSet):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I assume the code you've posted *doesn't* work, so... what does it do? Give a [mre]. Also a conditional in an if to return True or False is pointless, just `return len(number) == len(numberSet)`.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the number is provided as a string (you can't convert an int variable to list). Try:

```
def isUnique(num):
    number = str(num) # convert provided num to string
    numberSet = set(number)
    return len(number) == len(numberSet)
```

Comment: no need to convert to list first, set(number) is enough

Answer (score 1):

change the number to string first

```
str_number= str(number)
return len(str_number)==len(set(str_number))
```